# Azure DevOps Pip Install

Tags: python, azure, pip, azure-devops, release

I am getting the following error when trying to deploy my build release for a python/flask web app:-

[image: Release Error]

I created a python command task with the following -

> pip install --upgrade

However, error persists.

Comment: Have you tried using the recommended command `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: Yes - tried executing that command in the pipeline and error persists.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you try to disable\suppress this error\warning (because its pretty harmless):

```
[global]
disable-pip-version-check = True
```

On many linux the default location for the pip configuration file is $HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf. You can always look that up in the [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file).